# SELECT LIMIT ORDER BY starting with arbitrary column value in auto-incremented id

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, limit

I'm kind of a middle of the road guy.  I can handle client-side/server-side OK, but CSS and db mystify me.

I'm not even sure how to frame this question.

In a LAMP environment, I want to return LIMIT 20 from a view, ORDERED BY a date column.  The catch that I can't figure out or put into the correct google/stack terms is that I want that LIMIT to start with an arbitrary value in the auto-increment ID column.

I can make a hash of it by returning the phone book into PHP and go from there, but I have no idea what's most efficient: putting it on the db or the server-side.  Should I make MySQL (if it's even possible) spit out 20 values starting at a certain point resulting from the ORDERED date but based upon the auto-increment id, or should I output everything to the server-side, find the point in the array that I'm looking for, and return that and the subsequent 19 values?

If it's more efficient to return it from the db, could someone help me with the SELECT?

As usual, praying to the MySQL gods to save me from my ignorance in db desperation.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: how do your records looked like? can also add your desired result?

Comment: do you maybe want to do SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > {minimal autoincrement index value} ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 20?

Comment: @john woo thank-you very much for responding, but I don't understand the question.  please bear with me, databases are incredibly far from my expertise and understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > desired_id ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 20
```

where `desired_id` is your desired arbitrary value in the autoincrement ID column.

What this means is, that database will find all values with id higher than `desired_id` and order them in descend order and will return only first 20 rows.